# Possible to move Program Counter to a far-off memory address immediately?

Tags: binary, hex, lc3, machine-code

I'm trying to adapt a program that counts the occurrences of a char in a file to store a list of the hex addresses where the matches occurred in a far-off memory location. Code:

```
011 0000 0000 0000 ;Codes x3000 as Load-address of program
0101 010 010 1 00000 ;R2 <- 0
0010 011 000010000 ;R3 <- M[x3012]
1111 0000 0010 0011 ;TRAP x23 (Loads INPUT into R0)
0110 001 011 000000 ;R1 <- M[R3]
;LOOP BEGINS HERE
0001 100 001 1 11100 ;R4 <- R1 - EOT
0000 010 000001000 ;If above = 0, exit loop
1001 001 001 111111 ;R1 <- NOT R1
0001 001 001 1 00001 ;R1 <- R1 + 1
0001 001 001 0 00 000 ;R1 <- R1 + R0
0000 101 000000001 ;If above != 0, do NOT increment counter
0001 010 010 1 00001 ;R2 <- R2 + 1 (increment counter)
0001 011 011 1 00001 ;R3 <- R3 + 1 (increments pointer to next char in file)
0110 001 011 000000 ;R1 <- M[R3] (loads next char into R1)
0000 111 111110110 ;BRnzp x3004 (unconditionally RETURN to loop start)
;LOOP ENDS HERE
0010 000 000000100 ;R0 <- M[x3013]
0001 000 000 0 00 010 ;R0 <- R0 + R2
1111 0000 0010 0001 ;TRAP x21 (OUTPUT)
1111 0000 0010 0101 ;TRAP x25 (HALT)
0011 0001 0000 0000 ;Codes x3100 for the starting address of the file
0000 000 000110000 ;ASCII template
```

So my program starts at memory address x3000. I want to begin the set of instructions that will handle the list at x300B (below the "increment R2" instruction). Trouble is, I want to start the list at x3500, and I don't know of an "efficient" way to get there.

My original plan was to use a Load Indirect (LDI) instruction, but because of sign-extension, the 9-bit offset only allows an offset of at most x00FF = 0000 0000 1111 1111, which only takes me from x300C (x300B with program counter incremented) to x310B.

The only real "workaround" I've come up with is to use a Load Effective Address (LEA) instructions to store the address x310B in a register (say R5), then store the value x00FF in R6, and repeatedly add R6 to R5 until I get to x3408 (that would take 3 ADD instructions), at which point I'd store the value x0092 in R6, add that to R5, and I'd FINALLY have x3500 in R5.

At that point, the rest is trivial (store R3 in (R5 + counter), which would put the address of the current match into the appropriate "spot" on the list)

I haven't actually done this yet because the whole method of getting to x3500 I described above seems really cumbersome and clumsy. I can't shake the feeling that there has to be a better, faster way to move that many memory addresses at the same time.

Is it possible to move from x300C to x3500 in a single instruction? Even two would be better than what I've currently got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want to do that, it is possible but a simpler method would be to use LD (opcode 0010) and LDR (opcode 0110)  to do this.  No need to have the PC jump to x3500 (which would start executing the data in your array which is bad)

Have an address contain the bits 0011 0101 0000 0000
Opcode 0010 will allow you to pull the x3500 into a register.  Opcode 0110 will then allow you to load values from your array.